# Session get null before the session time out periods in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my MVC3 application I'm using Session Collection to maintain all the sessions through out the application, but suddenly my session get null before the session time out period

```
<sessionState timeout="20" mode="InProc"></sessionState>
```

This is how I set session timeout in Web.Config file.

Comment: Do you mean to say you are not able to access the session collection at all? Or is it timing out after certain time? Or is after some action? Are you running in debug mode in VS

Comment: When session getting null, need more clarification.

Comment: If I'm using application at a stretch and finish the process then nothing will happens to session, but when site is ideal for around 5 min then suddenly it get null, I'm confusing since this is the first time I'm facing such situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've able to overcome this issue by adding Action filter to my controller

```
using System.Web.SessionState;

[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Required)]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
}
```

Now I can ideal my site for longer time